# Having trouble implementing -webkit-transform to scale up images in a photo gallery

Tags: css, webkit, transform

I have a conceptual question about photo galleries like this:

http://www.nikesh.me/demo/image-hover.html

If you open this in a browser that supports CSS Transitions (for example Chrome), it will smoothly scale the hovered image whilst the zoomed version remains of a high quality.

This is accomplished by showing the non-zoomed images into a slightly smaller version than they really are, in essence the zoom shows them in their true dimensions.

So, normal images are first scaled down:

```
-webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
```

And then upon hover scaled up:

```
-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
```

My question: How is the initial scaling down supposed to work for browsers that do not support this method of scaling down? Try opening that gallery in IE to see what I mean, it shows the images not scaled down, which makes them too large and thereby they break the layout.

**What I want:**

- The full effect in browsers that support it. Important is that the zoomed version remains quality.
- No effect at all for browsers that do not support it, yet a solid original dimension so that no layout is broken
- It should work for both image orientations and there may be variety in image widths and heights too

Anyone? Preferably an elegant solution that does not need browser sniffing or javascript, but all answers are welcome.

Comment: IE supports a kind of scaling: `zoom`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting it to work without the use of javascript then it seems the only method you have is to forgo the initial scale down with css. You will want to do this in the "antiquated" way of adjusting the width and height of the image in the markup.

```
<img src="yourImageSrc" width="80%" height="80%">
```

This would allow you to still keep your layout in tact if the user agent is not up to date.

** I don't know if the percentage works in the literal height/width definition. But  you can always figure out the ratio you need and plug it in.

Comment: I made some progress but a few problems remain. Indeed a percentage alone does not cut it, I had to calculate the ratio between the actual image and scaled down image and use that as a literal width and height. This works. Two problems remain: 1) In Chrome (9) the zoomed in image is of an inferior quality. This is not what I expected given that I am intentionally loading images bigger than I show. 2) FF3.6 does correctly zoom the image into high quality, yet has no animation effect. This is no huge issue, but strange since I use FF 3.6 and this should be supported as of 3.5

Comment: Anyways, I am going to give you the bounty as soon as SO allows me. I think your answer is correct, although I will probably drop this feature it does not work as intended in any browser (animation + high quality zoom).